# How to integrate along velocity vector fields?

Tags: integration, reference-request, vector-fields

Let us assume I have sampled a vector field of "velocity" vectors : $\bf x \to {\bf v}({\bf x})$

How can I calculate a vector-field of orts-vectors where I end up after some time $t$?

Let us call say (${\bf x},t) \to {\bf s}_t({\bf x})$

---

Simple example (unless I am mistaken) :

$${\bf v}({\bf x}) = \begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}{\bf x} = \begin{bmatrix}-x_2\\x_1\end{bmatrix}$$

Should give $${\bf s}_t({\bf x}) = \begin{bmatrix}\cos(t)&\sin(t)\\-\sin(t)&\cos(t)\end{bmatrix}{\bf x}$$

If we "follow" the velocity field of a revolution, we will end up on a circle. Compare the in physics circular motion with constant speed.

My intuition tells me that this should be conceptually similar to integration in some sense. I also have some memory of a professor once telling me there is a connection to abstract algebra and Lie groups and Lie algebras. There was a corresponding "infinitesimal" rotation which by exponentiation was related to this integral. I am sorry if this all sounds very fuzzy.

What I mostly am after is some reference to literature of where to read more on this, although an explanation how to calculate the example is also welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that this is reminiscent of integration — you are trying to solve a differential equation.  Namely, if you have a relationship $\vec{v}=\vec{F}(\vec{x})$, then, since the definition of velocity is $\vec{v}=\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}$, one obtains the relation $\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}=\vec{F}(\vec{x})$.

This ODE does not have a general solution, but the specific example you cite, $$\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}=\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1\\1&0
\end{bmatrix}\vec{x}\mathrm{,}$$ does.  In particular, let $A$ be any matrix.  Then, for the same reason $x=Ce^{at}$ solves $\frac{dx}{dt}=ax$, the function $$\vec{x}=M\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(At)^j}{j!}}\right)\vec{x}_0$$ (where $M$ is an arbitrary constant matrix, and $\vec{x}_0$ an arbitrary constant vector) also satisfies $\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}=A\vec{x}$.